# Find array in another array and get index of result

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have this array:

```
    var arr = [
{attributes: [{name: "Impregnante", slug: "impregnante", option: "Nessuno"}, {name: "Tegole", slug: "tegole", option: "Senza Tegole"}], id:430, price:"1000"},
{attributes: [{name: "Impregnante", slug: "impregnante", option: "Nessuno"}, {name: "Tegole", slug: "tegole", option: "Rossi"}], id:431, price:"1025"},
{attributes: [{name: "Impregnante", slug: "impregnante", option: "Nessuno"}, {name: "Tegole", slug: "tegole", option: "Verdi"}], id:432, price:"1025"},
{attributes: [{name: "Impregnante", slug: "impregnante", option: "Trasparente"}, {name: "Tegole", slug: "tegole", option: "Senza Tegole"}], id:433, price:"1100"},
{attributes: [{name: "Impregnante", slug: "impregnante", option: "Trasparente"}, {name: "Tegole", slug: "tegole", option: "Rossi"}], id:434, price:"1125"},
{attributes: [{name: "Impregnante", slug: "impregnante", option: "Trasparente"}, {name: "Tegole", slug: "tegole", option: "Verdi"}], id:435, price:"1125"},
{attributes: [{name: "Impregnante", slug: "impregnante", option: "Noce"}, {name: "Tegole", slug: "tegole", option: "Senza Tegole"}], id:436, price:"1100"},
{attributes: [{name: "Impregnante", slug: "impregnante", option: "Noce"}, {name: "Tegole", slug: "tegole", option: "Rossi"}], id:437, price:"1125"},
{attributes: [{name: "Impregnante", slug: "impregnante", option: "Noce"}, {name: "Tegole", slug: "tegole", option: "Verdi"}], id:438, price:"1125"},
{attributes: [{name: "Impregnante", slug: "impregnante", option: "Castagno"}, {name: "Tegole", slug: "tegole", option: "Senza Tegole"}], id:439, price:"1100"},
{attributes: [{name: "Impregnante", slug: "impregnante", option: "Castagno"}, {name: "Tegole", slug: "tegole", option: "Rossi"}], id:440, price:"1125"},
{attributes: [{name: "Impregnante", slug: "impregnante", option: "Castagno"}, {name: "Tegole", slug: "tegole", option: "Verdi"}], id:441, price:"1125"}]
```

And another array:

```
var obj =  [{name: "Impregnante", slug: "impregnante", option: "Trasparente"}, {name: "Tegole", slug: "tegole", option: "Rossi"}];
```

Can someone give me an advice, how to find the obj in arr and return the id where obj was...
Thx in advance and so sorry for the language!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
const parseData = (arr, obj) => {
  let found = arr.find(a => JSON.stringify(a.attributes) === JSON.stringify(obj));
  return found ? found.id : null;
}

console.log(parseData(arr, obj)); //434
```

To provide objects shallow comparison I used `JSON.stringify()`. This approach requires strict order of attributes of objects involved in the operation. You may implement such a comparison in some another way, if this requirement isn't acceptable.

Comment: Thx, its working nice, but, what if i have this array like var obj2 = [{option: "Trasparente"}, {option: "Rossi"}]

Comment: Just make a comparison strict : `let found = arr.find(a => a.attributes[0].option === obj[0].option && a.attributes[1].option === obj[1].option);` -- depends on your need, the comparator could be customized in a hundred ways

Comment: Thx, the solution was simply, but im so novice in this programming language. Thx again!

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you:

Get the object:

```
var arrFilter = arr.filter(function(a, b){ return JSON.stringify(a.attributes) == JSON.stringify(obj) });

// if you need the property ID
arrFilter[0].id
```

Get the index:

```
var idx = arr.findIndex(function(a, b){ return JSON.stringify(a.attributes) == JSON.stringify(obj) })
```

If you want, you can use Arrow functions (Lambda expressions).